# Communication with GPRS module using C#, with TCP

Tags: tcp, tcplistener, gprs

I have searched a lot for this but could not find any specific answer that applies to my case. I have made device using GPS module and GSM/GPRS module with Arduino Mega 2560, and it sends me the location through SMS. Now I want to get the location parameters using GPRS. I have in mind to use TCP. I will send data through AT Commands from GPRS module, but I am confused on how to make a server on C#. I know that I would be needing a static/public IP for this. But I don't know how to get the public IP, and start receiving data which I send from GPRS module. Please please I need help because I am a beginner in Client/Server programming, and I am working on my final year project. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at this [TCP server and client example](https://github.com/vtortola/AynchronousTCPListener).

You will need a public static IP address. That is something you have to ask your broadband provider, and they will explain you the available options they have, probably you will have to pay extra money. You can use your current public IP address, that will be probably dynamic, but they don't use to change way to often, so whenever you are unable to connect, you will have to check if the IP changed or not, and set the new one.

This video series maybe a good introduction: https://vimeo.com/38103518

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am working on this and have purchased a static IP from my service provider. But now I am facing the problem of port forwarding. I will have to tell my router to forward requests for http to the local ip on a computer on my LAN. When I try to set the port in NAT (Network Address Translation) option in my router, it doesn't allow me to do that and says this port is already used by Reouter Web Server. I am stuck here. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Read your router manual, you should be able of putting the router webserver in another port. Ask in http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Server Code:

```
class Server
{
    TcpListener server = null;
    public Server(string ip, int port)
    {
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
        server.Start();
        StartListener();
    }

    public void StartListener()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection... ");
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleDeivce));
                t.Start(client);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
    }

    public void HandleDeivce(Object obj)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        string data = null;
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
        int i;

        while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
        {
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
            Console.WriteLine("{1}: Received: {0}", data, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            if (data.StartsWith("##"))
            {
                data = "LOAD";
            }
            else
            {
                data = "ON";
            }

            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("{1}: Sent: {0}", data, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)